# 3d graphics within c# winforms

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, directx

So i have this project to be made where in I am supposed to map boxes inside a bigger container and the ideal way to fit them in.
I can do all the math by taking input and providing the result as to how those boxes can be fit in along with the order(if needed), However, I have to display it too to the client for a better feel. So I need a simple way to draw different sized boxes inside a bigger container and show them by differentiating in color/size etc.
For eg :
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpMSz.png)

I need a way to render such an image given that i know the order to stack the boxes and the dimensions of each.

Comment: you can look at opentk or sharpdx for 3d graphics in c# https://opentk.github.io/ , http://sharpdx.org/

Comment: @catflier Could you please direct me to some sample code/tutorial as there are quite a few i searched but none of them could fit into my thinking currently.

Comment: The link to openTK is dead and it seems that it's been abandoned. SharpDX is still alive and kickin'.

Comment: OpenTK's active github link: https://github.com/opentk/opentk, documentation: https://opentk.net/